# Why doesn't this simple NSPredicate filter my array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, filtering, nspredicate

I have a very simple `NSPredicate` that's supposed to filter my array of custom objects.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.displayedSources);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
[self.displayedSources filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", self.displayedSources);
```

However, this leaves me with 0 results (even with *empty* `searchText`).

I know the array is populated with 26 objects of custom type, where the header looks like so

```
@interface NewsSourceObject : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString *objectId;
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString *name;
...
@end
```

I know the code is being executed, because I've added print statements logging the length of the array both before and after applying the predicate (26 - 0).

I've been pulling my hair out for over half a day with this, because I can't tell what's wrong.

**EDIT 1:**
I tried logging the contents of the array before and after applying the predicate (see top code block) using this `description` method for the objects:

```
- (NSString *)description {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.name];
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
2015-06-08 02:57:28.521 Newsloop[8554:1578121] (
  "ABC News",
  "BBC News",
  "Bleacher Report",
  "Business Insider",
  "BuzzFeed News",
  CNN,
  "Daily Mail Online",
  ...
)
2015-06-08 02:57:28.522 Newsloop[8554:1578121] (
)
```

Comment: Is the name field actually populated in your objects?

Comment: Yes, I tried printing out the array and all the name fields contain text

Comment: Unrelated but why are the property declarations "copy" not  "retain"?

Comment: Because `NSString` has a mutable subclass. So if my object is given a `NSMutableString` instead, any later changes to that `NSMutableString` won't affect the `name` property of my object. Just for safety.

Comment: "don't know why some of the strings have quotation marks" Irrelevant. It's just a way of displaying info in the console. If a value is multiple words, it gets quotation marks, that's all.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: So logging shows the array is _not_ empty. So why do you say it's empty?

Comment: Logging the array *before* applying the predicate shows it's not empty and the `name` fields are populated. Logging the array *after* the predicate has been applied yields an empty array.

Comment: Could you show that logging? Log `self.displayedSources` right before filtering and right after filtering, in that very first code you are showing. Just add the logging in there and show what you get.

Comment: And `searchText` contains the correct value? Because if it's empty you wouldn't get a result.

Comment: I believe an empty `searchText` should yield a full array(?), but regardless, yes: any value (such as just "A" or the full "ABC News") yields nothing.

Comment: I always knew it was something very simple I was overlooking, and you @MatthiasBauch telling me that an empty `searchText` yields an empty array got me on the right track. I'm using this code in a `SearchController`, so that when I tap to enter text, this filter method gets called with an empty `searchText` which leaves my array empty for when I try to type in other values later. 

I'm glad I finally figured it out, but I'm extremely annoyed something as simple as this took as long as it did. But a big thanks to everyone here! Without you I would've been stuck on this for even longer.

Comment: Your predicate works fine for me, so something else must be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild speculation, but my theory is that you don't "reset" `self.displayedSources` after running the filter. Since you filter the array in place one wrong keystroke clears the array forever.

You probably run that part of code while `searchText` still contains the empty string. Which basically removes all your objects from the array. Every consecutive key stroke runs a filter on the empty array.

Store the filtered array in a different variable instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.displayedSources);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];

NSArray *filtered = [self.displayedSources filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, and I only beat you to it by a few seconds haha (check the original comment thread). Thanks a million for your help :)